# How to find Angular Velocity without knowing time. only Torque and Theta?

Tags: calculus, physics

In my Project of gravity arms drive, there are three arms that shift $120$ degree each. I can only calculate torque of each Theta. For example at arm A rotate 1 degree torque $1\ \mathrm{Nm}$. Torque= $Fl$, $F=mg$. I get torque from that equation. I get torque of all $360$ degree. But I can't calculate how much rotation per minute will get. Please advise me. I apologize for my english grammer.

Thanks to you all.[My arms drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nD4p9.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: I added my sample project photo. Thank You.

Comment: If there is a net constant torque (which I doubt given this looks like an attempt to design a perpetual motion machine) then this will produce a resultant angular acceleration. i.e. $T=I\frac{d \theta^2}{d t^2}$ where $I$ is the moment of inertia. This is the rotational analogue of Newton's second law. As in linear acceleration, calculated using Newton's Second Law, what determines the maximum linear/rotational speed is ultimately the frictional losses; wind resistance, bearing resistance etc.